# Proof of $a^n>n$ by non-analytic method

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there any proof of the fact that $a^n>n$ for all sufficiently large $n$ where $2>a>1$, without using methods from calculus?

Comment: What counts as calculus (or rather, what counts as _not calculus_)?

Comment: This is a difficult question but maybe the content of the tag "algebra-precalculus" be of some help.

Comment: Doesn't help me in the least, unfortunately, since where I come from the courses are organised differently. Precalculus and calculus are unknown here.

Comment: You may read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus) also.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $\epsilon:=a-1>0$.  Then, by the Binomial Theorem,
$$a^n=(1+\epsilon)^n=\sum_{r=0}^n\,\binom{n}{r}\,\epsilon^r\geq 1+n\epsilon+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\epsilon^2>n\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\epsilon^2\right)\,.$$
If $n\geq1+\frac{2}{\epsilon^2}$, then you fill in the detail.

Answer (score 1):

Set $a=1+h\ (h>0)$. Then
$$ a^n=(1+h)^n\ge 1+nh+\frac{n(n-1)h^2}2\ge1+\frac{n(n-1)h^2}2. $$
Thus we're sure $a^n>n\;$ if $\;\dfrac{n-1}2h^2\ge1$, i.e. if $\;n\ge\left\lfloor\dfrac2{h^2}\right\rfloor$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very sloppy answer, which is also elementary.  If $a>1$, then there is some $N$ such that $a^N>2$.  So we know that 
$$
a^n > 2^{n/N},
$$
which means that if we can show that 
$$
2^{n/N} > n
$$
for sufficiently large $n$, then we're done.  Now it is not hard to show that $2^n > n^2$ for $n\geq 3$, as this can be done by induction.  So now we are reduced to finding large enough $n$ that
$$
n^2 / N^2 > n,
$$
which happens when $n>N^2$.